# trigger functions no longer working after implement ajax scroll pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have developed an audio platform similar to Soundcloud and it all works(ed) perfectly! Until I decided to create an **Ajax** scroll pagination.

Both the pagination and **Ajax** work fine. However, I have noticed some **JavaScript** that used to work before implementing **Ajax**, which no longer does.

The script has a pretty simple duty; play a track when the user clicks the play button (or pause when the user clicks on it again). Then, once the track has finished, move on to the next track until it finally reaches the end.

What happens now is, when the page first loads up (along with the 10 tracks that load with the page), the `script` will work as it is supposed to. But, when the user scrolls down to get more results to load, if the user clicks on one of the newly loaded tracks play button, the track either won't play, or it will play over the other track which is supposed to pause (and then all the buttons just completely stop working).

Here is **all** of the `feed.js` (removed as much bloat code as possible, and placed comments):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // on page load
    var tp = 1; // set track page equal to one
    loadTracks(tp); // then load all of the tracks

    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.f-outer-container').on('scroll', function() { // when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page load more tracks
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                tp++; 
                loadTracks(tp);
            }
        });
    });
    function loadTracks(track_page){
        $.post('/spectrum-rr/core/_func/functions/loadTrack.php', {'page': tp}, function(data){ // get send and get data from loadTrack.php
            $("#f-ap__aj").append(data); // append those tracks in the feed

            // player functions
            $(".track-w__trigger").click(function(){ // when the play button is clicked
                var tid = $(this).attr('aria-trackid'), // get its track id
                    tiW = 'w' + tid + 'w',
                    tiW = eval(tiW); // set the waveform object

                playPauseButton(this, tiW, tid); 
            });
        });
    }
});

// player functionality
function playPauseButton(button, wave, trackID){ // once the function has been called
    pausePrevious(button); // pause the previous track (this doesn't work when more ajax results are loaded)
    var button = $(button);

    if(wave.isPlaying()){ // if the wave is playing; stop it
        button.removeClass("playing");
        wave.pause();
    } else { // vice versa
        button.addClass("playing"); 
        wave.play();
    }
    var waveDuration = wave.getDuration();
    var nextTrack = ++trackID; 

    var checkAudioFinished = setInterval(function(){ // check if the audio has finished playing every second
        if(wave.getCurrentTime() >= waveDuration){ // if it has
            button.removeClass("playing"); // remove it's buttons "playing" class
            $('#w' + nextTrack + 'w-trigger').trigger('click'); // play the next song on the playlist by incrementing the id
            clearInterval(checkAudioFinished);
        }    
    }, 1000);
}
function pausePrevious(b){
    $(".playing").not(b).each(function(){ // when this function is triggered
        $(".playing").trigger('click'); // pause all of the other tracks (by simulating the click of their pause buttons
        $(".playing").removeClass("playing"); // remove it's class too
    });
}
```

I feel these problems are occurring due to the use of `$(document).ready();`. Forcing these functions to only be available to those tracks that were already loaded. However, I am not sure.

Here is the **HTML** that gets sent back from each request (in 10s):

```
<div class="f-wave-send f-waveform-container">
    <div aria-trackid="1" class="track-w__trigger" id="w1w-trigger"></div> <!-- the "1" is generated by PHP. it is incremented for every div !-->
    <div class="f-waveform-outer-container">
        <div aria-trackid="1" class="track-w__waveform" id="w1-w"></div>
        <script>
            var w1w = WaveSurfer.create({ // wavesurfer script (this is the "wave" object that is being triggered inside the playPauseButton() function !-->
                container: '#w1-w',
                barWidth: 2,
            });
            w1w.load('./player/audio/sampleaudio.mp3');             
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone could give me insight as to what might be going on (or any tips in improving my code for that matter), it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why u place $(".track-w__trigger").click inside $.post('/spectrum-rr/core/_func/functions/loadTrack.php'. Just move out $(".track-w__trigger").click ouside the  $.post

Comment: @errorare it fails to work otherwise :/ this was the only way I could get it to work unfortunately

Comment: @badjuju use event delegation instead see my suggesstion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

You should not bind an click event each time load happens and it should be moved out of your loadTracks, instead you shuold apply event delegation.

```
           // player functions
            $(document).on('click', '.track-w__trigger', function(){ // when the play button is clicked
                var tid = $(this).attr('aria-trackid'), // get its track id
                    tiW = 'w' + tid + 'w',
                    tiW = eval(tiW); // set the waveform object

                playPauseButton(this, tiW, tid); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // on page load
var tp = 1; // set track page equal to one
loadTracks(tp); // then load all of the tracks

jQuery(function($) {
    $('.f-outer-container').on('scroll', function() { // when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page load more tracks
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            tp++; 
            loadTracks(tp);
        }
    });
});
function loadTracks(track_page){
    $.post('/spectrum-rr/core/_func/functions/loadTrack.php', {'page': tp}, function(data){ // get send and get data from loadTrack.php
        $("#f-ap__aj").append(data); // append those tracks in the feed
    });
}

// player functions
        $(".track-w__trigger").on("click",function(){ // when the play button is clicked
            var tid = $(this).attr('aria-trackid'); // get its track id
                tiW = 'w' + tid + 'w';
                tiW = eval(tiW); // set the waveform object

            playPauseButton(this, tiW, tid); 
        });

});
```

Just move out $(".track-w__trigger").click outside $.post and change it to $(".track-w__trigger").on("click",function()